# How to reset cache from django templates?

Tags: django, apache

I have site on django. I changed code of application. But there no effect.(reset Apache). It is possibly depend of cache template:

```
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'dbtemplates.loader.Loader',
    ('django.template.loaders.cached.Loader', (
            'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
            'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
    )),
```

But I don't know how to refresh, or delete, or reset cache.Thank's for help,

Comment: What makes you think the template loaders have anything to do with the cache?

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.template.loader import template_source_loaders

def reset_template_cache():
    if not template_source_loaders:
        return

    for loader in template_source_loaders:
        loader.reset()
```

There you go :)

Answer (score 0):

This is only my intuition, but I think that this caching template is in the database.

Delete the dbtemplates and I think that you don't have any problem.... but only is intuition

PS: "dbtemplates.loader.Loader" is the devil

Comment: do u mean: TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
            'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
            'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader')?

Comment: don't you understand the TEMPLATE_LOADERS means?

Comment: I understand. I try TEMPLATE_LOADERS without 'dbtemplates.loader.Loader', but there is no effect to.

Comment: if you code it TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
            'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
            'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
    ) works?

Comment: what is your cache backend? settings.CACHES

Comment: CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
        'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211',
        'TIMEOUT': 600,
        'OPTIONS': {
                #'MAX_ENTRIES': 100000,
        }
    }
}

Comment: reset the memcached: /etc/init.d/memcached restart